# Passing expression to custom function in R

Tags: r

I need to use `replicate` inside a custom function (the details are not important but it involves random number generation.

Let's say I'm using: `rnorm(2)`

I know I can repeat the expression 10 times using `replicate(10, rnorm(2))`

Now, I want to be able to use `replicate` inside a function since I need to post-process the output and I also want to be able to change the replicated expression, so I'm trying something like this:

```
fn <- function(expression) replicate(10, expression)
```

But when I run the function I get the exact same numbers repeated 10 times:

```
fn(rnorm(2))
```

I know that `fn` is getting the result of `rnorm(2)` and that's why it is repeating the numbers so I need to tell `fn` not to evaluate `expression`. I've been digging into this and it seems I need to use `substitute` inside `fn` but I can't make it work.

Comment: Would you be unsatisfied with `fn1 <- function(FUN,...){ sapply(seq_len(10),FUN = FUN,...)}; fn1(rnorm,n = 2)`?

Comment: I want to pass parameters to the expression but also outside it (like the number times to replicate), so I did: `myfn <- function(a, b, c) a*b*rnorm(c);
fn1 <- function(times, FUN, ...){ sapply(seq_len(times), FUN=FUN, ...)};
fn1(times=10, FUN=myfn, 1, 2, 3)`; but I'm getting: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (3)` any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to pass thought the expression, you can use `...` like

```
fn <- function(...) replicate(10, ...)
```

That doesn't allow you to interact with that particular parameter and it assumes that you want to pass along all parameters.

You could capture the expression and pass it along with

```
fn <- function(a) do.call("replicate", list(10, substitute(a)))
```

as well. You need to use `do.call` to get pass along the unevaluated expression to `replicate.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you please elaborate on why using `...` works?